# Horizontal and vertical photos in same row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, photo-gallery

How set three photos like this:
[image]

The photos cover all width only if i set in css width: 100vh for all, but then middle photo is disproportionate (black frames show how i would like it to look like):
[image]

When i set middle photo width individually is worst because even i set 100vh width everything is breaking and it looks like this:
[image]

Here is HTMl code:

```
<main>

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row justify-content-sm-center">

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">

            <figure class="description">

                <a href="img/projects/home/1.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery" data-gallery="multiimages"><img src="img/projects/home/test2.jpg" class="img-fluid img"></a>

            </figure>

        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">

            <figure class="description">

                <a href="img/projects/home/2.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery" data-gallery="multiimages"><img src="img/projects/home/test1.jpg" class="img-fluid img"></a>

            </figure>

        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">

            <figure class="description">

                <a href="img/projects/home/3.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery" data-gallery="multiimages"><img src="img/projects/home/test2.jpg" class="img-fluid img"></a>

            </figure>

        </div>

</div>
```

I dont know how to it and not to lose responsiveness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Setting one column width` in the Bootstrap Grid System.

Here's the documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#setting-one-column-width

This would be the code (Replace the column values with images or background-images):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      2 of 3 (wider)
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Awesome, but now how can i set for small screen col-12?

Comment: Now for every screen width i have 3 photos in a row. For small screen (i mean phone screen) in one row should be one photo.

Comment: @BlvckCodeGuy Here's a documentation too: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#variable-width-content